# How to change NFS export allowed IP addresses on Mac OS X Server (Tiger)?

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, nfs

I am running NFS on a Mac OS X Server 10.4. I had originally set up the NFS exports in the GUI, and restricted the IP addresses in the GUI to which it can export.

Right now, I only have command-line (ssh) access to the Mac. When I run `showmount -e`, it returns

```
/Volumes/Data/myshare             172.18.150.138 172.18.150.130
```

which is correct. However, I want to change the IP addresses to which it is exported to 172.18.150.**134** and 172.18.150.**132**.

When I run `nicl . -list /exports`, it prints

```
116        /Volumes/Data/myshare
```

but I do not know how to change any information in `nicl`.

There is no `/etc/exports` file, and when I run `find / -exec grep -H "172.18.150" {} \;` nothing comes up. `nfsd` is running.

How can I change the allowed IP addresses in the command-line on Mac OS X Server 10.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger uses NetInfo database, which was [discontinued in 10.5 Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetInfo_Manager). For 10.4:

```
nicl . -delete 116 clients 172.18.150.130
nicl . -delete 116 clients 172.18.150.138
nicl . -append 116 clients 172.18.150.132
nicl . -append 116 clients 172.18.150.134
```

Then restart the NFS server.